# Add values in Splunk if rows match

Tags: splunk

I have a splunk query that returns application traffic on a daily basis.

```
AppID   AppBindID   ServerIP     HostName AppServer tree DailyCount
17159   cn=id1     123.45.678.10   server1  serverA LDAP    3   
17159   cn=id1     123.45.678.10   server1  serverA LDAP    7   
17159   cn=id2     123.45.678.11   server1  serverA LDAP    3
```

I want to be able to identify duplicates in the data from columns 1-6 and then add the values from column 7 to make a single unique row.

Desired output:

```
AppID   AppBindID   ServerIP     HostName AppServer tree DailyCount
17159   cn=id1     123.45.678.10   server1  serverA LDAP    10  
17159   cn=id2     123.45.678.11   server1  serverA LDAP    3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use stats to sum a field based on several other fields.

```
index=... | stats sum(DailyCount) as DailyCount by AppId, AppBindID, ServerIP, Hostname, AppServer, tree
```